# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable using curl to download content from appannie

Tags: curl, appannie

I am using `curl` to download the content from appannie.com using the API key like this:

```
curl -H -O "Authorization: bearer somekey" https://www.appannie.com/downloadlink>download.csv
```

I get the error

```
[2]   Done                    breakdown=product
[3]   Done                    countries=ALL
[4]-  Done                    date=2015-12-27~2016-01-25
[5]+  Done                    chart_type=all
$ curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Authorization
<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I look at [documentation for `curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), it tells me you're using it wrong. For example, compare what `-O` is supposed to do (direct output) and what you are trying to do with it (set headers.)

Perhaps you'd like to try this instead; it's very similar to what is listed in [App Annie's quickstart guide](https://support.appannie.com/hc/en-us/articles/204208794-1-Quick-Start-):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer somekey" -o download.csv https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/...
```

I assume you're using an example URL in your question, but do make sure you're using the correct hostname as well (api.appannie.com vs. www.appannie.com).

Comment: I can't use --user because I need to pass a header with API key .

Comment: Authentication in Appannie using basic over HTTPS was deprecated. So I can't do basic --user USER[:PASSWORD]  Server user and password. Thanks.